# Overriding a instance property in swift (help)

Tags: swift, inheritance, overriding

Hi I have recently started learning swift , when  was reading the inheritance chapter I came across this problem, so I have created a vehicle class as my super class and a car class as my subclass the car class inherits from vehicle class and after that I have created an automaticCar class as another subclass which inherits from car class (please see code if there is any ambiguity) , so when I try to override the dangerText it seems like Xcode jumps over the code and does not change the dangerText :-(
please let me know if I am doing something wrong , I'm not looking for an alternative way , therefore please answer by correcting my code with an override solution
Thanks in advance !

```
import Foundation
class viehcle {
//SuperClass viehcle
var currentSpeed = 0
let maxSpeed = 180
var descripion:String{
    return "Current speed is \(currentSpeed)"
 }
}
class car:viehcle{
//SubClass car inherits from viehcle
var currentGear = 1
var dangerText = ""
//override of description instance property
override var descripion: String{
    return ("The current speed is \(super.currentSpeed) and the gear is \(currentGear) \(dangerText)")
 }
}
class AutomaticCar:car{
//SubClass AutomaticCar which inherits fom superClass car 


//override of dangerText instance property of car
override var dangerText: String{
    didSet{
        if currentSpeed>maxSpeed{
            let slowDown = "Slow Down !"
            dangerText = dangerText.stringByAppendingString(slowDown)
        }
    }
}
//override current speed instance property of car
override var currentSpeed: Int{
    didSet{

        currentGear = (currentSpeed/40)+1

        if currentGear <= 4 {

        currentGear = self.currentGear

        }
        else{
            currentGear = 4
           }
       }
  }
}

var myCar = car() // obj/instance created from car class
var myAutomaticCar = AutomaticCar() // obj/instance created from AutomaticCar class
myAutomaticCar.currentSpeed = 300 // set Automatic car's current speed to 300

print(myCar.descripion)
print(myAutomaticCar.descripion)
```

Comment: your code is correct. it's working fine in xcode 7.2.

Comment: its really weird its not working correctly in my Xcode , thanks for answering ! the slow down text isn't printed in my version ??

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: what issues you are facing? what  error xcode gives you?

Comment: if you set a breakpoint on the override dangerText you'll see that the compiler won't break at that line and afterwards the slow down text isn't printed!

Comment: you are not setting anything into dangertext. so its not printed.

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a small mistake in the **AutomaticCar** class. In that class no need to override the **dangerText**, instead of that when you set the new value to the **currentSpeed** just update the dangerText as shown below...

```
class AutomaticCar:car {
    override var currentSpeed: Int {
        didSet {
            currentGear = (currentSpeed/40)+1
            if currentGear <= 4 {
                currentGear = self.currentGear
            }
            else{
                currentGear = 4
            }
            if currentSpeed > maxSpeed {
                let slowDown = "Slow Down !"
                dangerText = dangerText.stringByAppendingString(slowDown)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check now the **dangerText** will come with the description for the given currentSpeed and maxSpeed.